# How to remove summary text In yii2?

Tags: gridview, yii2

[image]

I want to remove the line which is show in attached screen shot from my page.How can I edit this from my yii2 project

Comment: hey if you are getting correct answers . please accept that answers it will help other users also.

Comment: I got correct answer that's why I vote to answer

Comment: you are just upvoting answers not accepting them @priyankaahire

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best way to do this is to override the layout of the `gridView` widget. By default, the widget will generate a layout based on this pattern; `{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}`. You can control over what appears in the widget like this;

```
echo GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'layout' => '{items}\n{pager}',
   'columns' => [
    // ...
      ],
]);
```

Comment: Pay attention that `\n` needs double quotes.

Answer (score 12):

In `gridview` options set `summary` to `NULL`

```
echo GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'summary' => '',
   'columns' => [
    // ...
      ],
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your grid view , use summary as empty:

```
   echo GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'summary' => '',

]);
```

For more options of grid view check this link [click here...](http://www.yiigridview::widget([)