# How to hide total display result in grid view for YII(1)?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

[image]

May I know how to hide the total display result shown as above? what code need to add to hide the text?

Comment: Suggestion, you can do it using css or javascript jquery.

Comment: Are you using Datatable library ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409636/how-to-remove-summary-class-in-yii2

Comment: thanks everyone! But i found problem solve it with just add 'summaryText' => ''

Answer (score 1):

Set `summaryText => ''`

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'summaryText' => '',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
?>
```

**OR**

Set `template` property

```
<?= GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'template' => '{items}\n{pager}',
?>
```

[Gridview summaryText property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#summaryText-detail)

[Gridview template property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#template-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting `$summaryOptions = ['display' => 'none']` in the GridView.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$summaryOptions-detail